# Selenium webdriver finding element in next link

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

open main(home) page and then go to login page using click() function , now i want to find element in this page how could I?

here is my code ...

```
import unittest,time,re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        #self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox","http://www.google.com/")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://bitbucket.org/")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("user-options")
        elem = elem.find_element_by_class_name("login-link")
        elem.click()
        print "check"

        #elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.elementToBeVisible(By.name("username")));
        #elem.send_keys("my_username@bitbucket.org")

        user_name_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
        password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')

        user_name_field.send_keys('your_user_name')
        password_field.send_keys('your_password')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
        #self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I got this error  (file name python_org_search.py)

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_search_in_python_org (__main__.PythonOrgSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_org_search.py", line 25, in test_search_in_python_org
    user_name_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 197, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_username"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpKo1TXx/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8860)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpKo1TXx/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8869)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpKo1TXx/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpKo1TXx/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpKo1TXx/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 30.994s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I tried other solutions as well but still same error .

Comment: I tried your code directly on my machine - it worked perfectly.
If it still fails - give your browser some time to breath:
Add the `implicitly_wait` to the driver and the `time.sleep` like described below.

Comment: The `implicitly_wait` should be added to the driver directly after initialization. And the `time.sleep` should be added after your `print check` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better should try to retrieve unique elements like the username field and password field by it's id. The `name` might not be unique and misleading.

Try the following `find_element_by_id('id_username')` and `find_element_by_id('id_password')`.

Sometimes you need to wait some time that your browser renders the page
and retrieves all contents - so it can be useful to wait some time, 
e.g. three seconds before you look deeper for elements.

**Code**

```
import time

time.sleep(3)
user_name_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')

user_name_field.send_keys('your_user_name')
password_field.send_keys('your_password')

password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
...
```

Moreover, I recommend you to use different variables names for the different fields. The variable `elem` could lead to difficult bugs.

Three seconds of waiting time like mentioned above can be unreliable - a more structured way of assuring some waiting time is it to tell it your `driver` through `implicitly_wait`:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30) # maximally wait 30 seconds before raising an exception.

# ...
# go to the page etc.
```

There are two ways of waiting time a driver can do:

- **Wait explicitly**: The driver waits this time before executing every next step.
- **Wait implicitly**: If you look for an element the driver searches for this time before he raises an exception.

For more details see the documentation: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

Comment: How it behaves when you add the `time.sleep()` and the `implicitly_waint()` there?

Comment: ok ..driver.implicitly_wait(30) did that job  :)
but i dont know why ? can you explain little bit how this line is working and making my code executable?

Comment: `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` forces the driver to search an element for maximally 30 seconds before throwing an exception. The default value of this configuration is zero seconds. So if the driver retrieved a website, but it is not fully available it immediately throws an exception - by implicitly wait it searches for an 30 seconds more.

Answer (score 1):

The following code use `elem` of previous page, which does not exist.

```
elem = elem.find_element_by_name("username")
```

Instead, you should use `driver`:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
```

Comment: still not working.
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}'

Comment: @GauravJain, It's strage. I tested with the code myself, and it worked. Try `driver.find_element_by_id("id_username")` as Jon suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
elem = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));

elem.send_keys("my_username@bitbucket.org");
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'elementToBeVisible'

Comment: My bad just updated my answer. btw this is java u need to change to python equivalent.

Comment: This question is tagged `python`, not `java`.

Answer (score -1):

To fill any type of form...the best method is go through its name in any case where ever available.

```
    driver=self.webdriver
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("XXXXX")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("XXXXX")
```

Comment: Why do you `click` the `username` item?

Comment: @Jon If we wont add that click() then the driver will not know where to send the keys(let say combo box for an user name)...so if we click on it then the cursor blinks in the combo box where we can pass the value...just try the above and let me know the result..thanks